# Replace commas enclosed in curly braces

Tags: python, json, regex, python-3.x

I try to replace commas with semicolons enclosed in curly braces.

Sample string:

```
text = "a,b,{'c','d','e','f'},g,h"
```

I am aware that it comes down to lookbehinds and lookaheads, but somehow it won't work like I want it to:

```
substr = re.sub(r"(?<=\{)(.+?)(,)(?=.+\})",r"\1;", text)
```

It returns:

```
a,b,{'c';'d','e','f'},g,h
```

However, I am aiming for the following:

```
a,b,{'c';'d';'e';'f'},g,h
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?
Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: Is there always just one set of curly braces in your string?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is an excerpt of an UTF-8 encoded API response which I want to parse into a CSV file.

Answer (score 3):

You can match the whole block `{...}` (with `{[^{}]+}`) and replace commas inside it only with a lambda:

```
import re
text = "a,b,{'c','d','e','f'},g,h"
print(re.sub(r"{[^{}]+}", lambda x: x.group(0).replace(",", ";"), text))
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Jz7Zv8)

Output: `a,b,{'c';'d';'e';'f'},g,h`

By declaring `lambda x` we can get access to each match object, and get the whole match value using `x.group(0)`. Then, all we need is replace a comma with a semi-colon.

**This regex does not support recursive patterns**. To use a recursive pattern, you need [*PyPi regex* module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). Something like `m = regex.sub(r"\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*}", lambda x: x.group(0).replace(",", ";"), text)` should work.

Comment: Wow that works like a charm. I got so hung up on trying to catch the multiple commas that I totally forgot you can just catch everything in between the braces and then just use the good old replace function to replace those characters you need to replace.

Comment: If you have nested `{}`s, you might want to have a look at Jaco's solution.

Comment: It doesn't work with nested brackets, e.g: `"a,{b,{'c','d','e','f'},g,h}"`

Comment: @Jaco: It does not since `re` does not support recursion. However, `regex` module does.

Comment: @stribizhev Just downloaded `regex` module. Can you explain the `(?R)` part of  `r"\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*}"` regex? Is it an recursion indicator, e.g. match if characters following the opening brace are not `{}` or if they are rerun the regex starting with the now matched `{`?

Comment: `(?R)` is a resursion construct telling the regex engine to repeat the *whole pattern*. From the docs page: *`(?R)` or `(?0)` tries to match the entire regex recursively.* It comes from PCRE. You can see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/kG0bO8/1).

Answer (score 2):

Below I have posted a solution that does not rely on an regular expression. It uses a stack (`list`) to determine if a character is inside a curly bracket `{`. Regular expression are more elegant, however, they can be harder to modify when requirements change. Please note that the example below also works for nested brackets.

```
text = "a,b,{'c','d','e','f'},g,h"
output=''
stack = []
for char in text:
    if char == '{':
        stack.append(char)
    elif char == '}':
        stack.pop()    
    #Check if we are inside a curly bracket
    if len(stack)>0 and char==',':
        output += ';'
    else:
        output += char
print output
```

This gives:

```
'a,b,{'c';'d';'e';'f'},g,h
```

You can also rewrite this as a `map` function if you use a the global variable for `stack`:

```
stack = []


def replace_comma_in_curly_brackets(char):
    if char == '{':
       stack.append(char)
    elif char == '}':
        stack.pop()    
    #Check if we are inside a curly bracket
    if len(stack)>0 and char==',':
        return ';'

    return char

text = "a,b,{'c','d','e','f'},g,h"
print ''.join(map(str, map(replace_comma_in_curly_brackets,text)))
```

Regarding performance, when running the above two methods and the regular expression solution proposed by @stribizhev on the test string at the end of this post, I get the following timings:

1. Regular expression (@stribizshev): 0.38 seconds
2. Map function: 26.3 seconds
3. For loop: 251 seconds

This is the test string that is 55,300,00 characters long:

```
 text = "a,able,about,across,after,all,almost,{also,am,among,an,and,any,are,as,at,be,because},been,but,by,can,cannot,could,dear,did,do,does,either,else,ever,every,for,from,get,got,had,has,have,he,her,hers,him,his,how,however,i,if,in,into,is,it,its,just,least,let,like,likely,may,me,might,most,must,my,neither,no,nor,not,of,off,often,on,only,or,other,our,own,rather,said,say,says,she,should,since,so,some,than,that,the,their,them,then,there,these,they,this,tis,to,too,twas,us,wants,was,we,were,what,when,where,which,while,who,whom,why,will,with,would,yet,you,your" * 100000
```

Comment: Quite a nice idea.
Do you know which method may be faster if looking at large chunks of text - regex or this iterative (re-)creation of the list? Afaik iterators tend to become relatively slow if handling large input.

Comment: I will run a quick test to compare the 2.

Comment: I have done a test on a string of 55,300,000 characters. The for loop is really slow and takes 251 seconds,the `map` function takes 26 seconds and the regular expression proposed by @stribizshev takes 0.38 seconds. The tests do not include the printing of the output.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have nested braces, it might be enough to just [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at each `,`
 if there is a closing `}` ahead without any opening `{` in between. Search for

```
,(?=[^{]*})
```

and replace with `;`

- `,` match a comma literally
- `(?=`...`)` the [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check
- if there's ahead `[^{]*` [any amount](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of characters, [that are not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `{`
- followed by a closing curly brace `}`

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bK5hY4/2)

Comment: Thank you for this sweet solution. Works like a charm.
Theres something I may have misunderstood: 
I always thought `{` and `}` need to be escaped with ` \ `, but it seems not to be the case when part of a capturing group. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: @VincentHahn It depends on the context and regex flavor. In most flavors you just need to escape it if you want to match a literal eg match string `a{0,1}`. In the context of my answer `{` `}` are not seen as part of a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) by the parser.

Comment: @VincentHahn In other words: As far as syntactically not a valid quantifier, it will match literally.